# Explain the word efficiency in this context

Tags: meaning

> Across the fire, Riga was
> binding a struggling deer with his usual brutal, callous **efficiency**.

Please explain the word "efficiency" in a simpler way. I already tried to translate it to my language but none seems to make sense. English is not my mother language.

Comment: Hello, An Nam, welcome to ELU! This question is actually not a good fit for this stack. [ELL.SE] would be a better place to post such questions, but do take the [tour] and remember to show your research, like what the dictionary says and why it is confusing. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

The author means Riga was doing the job directly with the only goal being getting the job done. No care was given to other considerations, like avoiding or ending the deer's suffering.

That is, if reducing the deer's suffering involved any extra action not needed to bind the deer properly: like killing the deer cleanly at the start, then that action would not be done. Not as a matter of wanting the deer to suffer, but simply because the action is superfluous to the task.

Comment: It may be worth noting that a skilled or experienced person working with their hands, such as a carpenter, chef, slaughterer of animals, etc, will not make any unnecessary movements or wasted actions, so there may also be this nuance present in 'efficiency' in this context.

Comment: Thank you Michael. I think I got what it means.

Answer (score 0):

Her efficiency means that she is doing what it takes to achieve the goal, not wasting time and resources. *Brutal efficiency* is something of an idiom, indicating unsentimental commitment to the ends regardless of the means.